# VS2013 Express - Template for Portable Class Library (C#)

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I'm working on a set of class libraries, and kept catching glimpses on the internet of "Portable Class Libraries". I thought it may be a good idea to make my class libraries portable, so I've installed Update 3, and yet no new templates have appeared to create them; am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried searching it in the upper right bar in the New Project dialog?

Comment: I've just tried it, but it's only coming up with the standard class library templates! :-(

Comment: Don't skip updates, Update 2 must be installed first since that's the one that added PCL support.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8) supports Portable Class Libraries as of Update 2.